# How to uncheck all checkboxes except the one using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a form that has multiple checkbox groups.

Each checkbox option has a custom html 5 attribute called `itemtype`. When the input of type="checkbox" changes, I need to evaluate the checkbox that was just selected. If the value of it's `data-itemtype` is equal to 'Skipper', I want to uncheck **all other** checkboxes that belong to the same group.

In other words, assume that I have multiple checkboxes and one of the checkbox options has a label called "None", if the user checks "None", Nothing should be selected but "None". I can't use a radio button here as I want the user to be able to check multiple options if "None" is not selected.

Here is a break down of my code

CHECKBOX GROUP 1

```
<input name="control_307[0][307:1003]" id="item_307_1003_0" value="307:1003" data-itemtype="Answer" type="checkbox"> Zulauf Ltd<br>
<input name="control_307[0][307:361]" id="item_307_361_0" value="307:361" data-itemtype="Answer" type="checkbox"> Ziemann, McLaughlin and Kohler
<input name="control_307[0][308:1013]" id="item_307_1013_0" value="308:1013" data-itemtype="Skipper" type="checkbox"> None<br>
```

CHECKBOX GROUP 2

```
<input name="control_1000[0][1000:999]" id="item_1000_999_0" value="307:1003" data-itemtype="Answer" type="checkbox"> First Options<br>
<input name="control_1000[0][1000:666]" id="item_1000_666_0" value="1000:666" data-itemtype="Answer" type="checkbox"> Some other option
<input name="control_1000[0][1000"123]" id="item_1000_123_0" value="308:1013" data-itemtype="Skipper" type="checkbox"> None<br>
```

I have create a fiddle to show you what I have done along with the entire form https://jsfiddle.net/8yf0v3xt/13/

I tried to do something like this but is is not working

```
$(:checkbox).change(function(){
        var skipper = $("input:checkbox[data-itemtype='Skipper']");

        if( skipper.is(":checked")){

            $(this).attr('checked', false); //uncheck all the boxes for the current group

            skipper.attr('checked', true); //re-check the box that caused everything to uncheck

        }
}).change();
```

What can I do to unckecl all the option if "None" is selected?

Comment: @MikeA I think this is what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/8yf0v3xt/14/

Comment: @ketan that just prevent the click on anycheck box that has the skipper itemtype.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hope this would work for you

```
$(:checkbox).change(function(){
        var skipper = $("input:checkbox[data-itemtype='Skipper']");

    if( skipper.is(":checked")){

        //$(":checkbox").attr('checked', false); //uncheck all the boxes for the current group

        //skipper.attr('checked', true); //re-check the box that caused everything to uncheck

        $(":checkbox").not(skipper).prop("checked",false);//THIS IS IMPORTANT

    }
}).change();
```

**UPDATE**

**[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8yf0v3xt/32/)**

**UPDATE 2**

**[WORKING FIDDLE 2](https://jsfiddle.net/8yf0v3xt/34/)**

```
 $(:checkbox).change(function(){
    var skipper = $("input:checkbox[data-itemtype='Skipper']");

if( skipper.is(":checked")){

    //$(":checkbox").attr('checked', false); //uncheck all the boxes for the current group

    //skipper.attr('checked', true); //re-check the box that caused everything to uncheck

    //$(":checkbox").not(skipper).prop("checked",false);//THIS IS IMPORTANT
    //THIS IS IMPORTANT
    $(this).closest(".survey-control-fieldset").find(":checkbox").not(skipper).prop("checked",false);

}
}).change();
```

**UPDATE 3**

**[WORKING FIDDLE 3](https://jsfiddle.net/8yf0v3xt/36/)**

```
$(:checkbox).change(function(){
        var skipper = $("input:checkbox[data-itemtype='Skipper']");

    if( skipper.is(":checked")){

        //$(":checkbox").attr('checked', false); //uncheck all the boxes for the current group

        //skipper.attr('checked', true); //re-check the box that caused everything to uncheck

        //$(":checkbox").not(skipper).prop("checked",false);//THIS IS IMPORTANT
        //THIS IS IMPORTANT
        $(this).closest(".survey-control-fieldset").find(":checkbox").not(skipper).prop("checked",false);

    }
    else
        {
            $(this).closest(".survey-control-fieldset").find(":checkbox[data-itemtype='Skipper']").prop("checked",false);
        }
    }).change();
```

**CONCLUSION**

Few points I noticed wrong in your code are as follows.

1. You were using `$(this).attr("checked",false);` to uncheck all
   checkboxes which is wrong. `$(this)` points to **CURRENT SINGLE
   ELEMENT only**, not all.
2. You were using `.attr("checked",false)` which is also incorrect, it
       should be either `.attr("checked","checked")` or
       `.prop("checked",true)`.

Comment: How is this putting any checkbox in the context of it's group? Will this not operate on all checkboxes on the page?

Comment: I have updated the code, with fiddle. We can filter the checkbox we want.

Comment: When you check a skipper in any fieldset, it will clear any checkbox on the page regardless of weather is it in the same fieldset or not. Is this the intended operation?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was talking about. Needed to use the parent fieldset as context to perform the checkbox manipulations. I think you got it! We'll see what OP thinks... :-)

Comment: @Hemal  Thank you very much. Fiddle 2 is what I am looking for. However, one thing I need to change is when some select an option after selecting "None". None should be unchecked.

Comment: @MikeA https://jsfiddle.net/8yf0v3xt/36/, this is what you asked. plz check FIDDLE 3

Comment: @Hemal thank you so much for your help. that solved my problem.